# Ajax not working wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**js file: (walking_log.js)**

```
  jQuery.ajax
  ({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          'action':'myaction'
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert('Happy new year 2015 :) ');
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert( 'Sorry! No Happy New year 2015 :(' );
        }
  });
```

**php file:**

```
// Ajax Handler.
function so_enqueue_scripts()
{
  $plugin_dir_path = dirname(__FILE__);
  $plugin_url = plugins_url();
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle', $plugin_url . '/walking-log/js/walking_log.js', array('jQuery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin_ajax.php' ) ) );

  add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'so_enqueue_scripts' );

function so_wp_ajax_function()
{
    die();
}
```

path of `walking_log.js` is right, i have opened it in the browser. I am getting the success failure alert. don't know why. any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
I am getting this on firebug.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://192.168.1.6/Interaction/exercise-log/%3C?php%20echo%20admin_url(%22admin-ajax.php%22);%20?%3E"
```

why this is happening?

Comment: You can not run php code in javascript file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In js file, This line must be causing the error..

```
 url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
```

You are calling a php function admin_url in js file. JS files will not call your php fn.

Your error confirms it .... Encoded url

```
%3C?php%20echo%20admin_url(%22admin-ajax.php%22);%20?%3E
```

Decoded URL

```
<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>
```

Comment: What is the difference between these two codes?
 url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
and
<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>

Comment: OP has placed a php script in .js file... How will it get executed ?